# Как патчить .exe файл ?

Tags: linux, exe

Как создавать патчи для текстовых файлов (исходников) - познакомилась со встроенными в *Linux* программами [diff и patch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WM_eWzNzx1o). А как создавать патчи для **.exe** файлов сидя на *Linux* , которые будут запускаться на *Windows* ? Потребуется ли wine ? И дополнительно получается, что когда программа обновляется, то на самом деле она патчится или обновление программы это иной процесс ?

Comment: патчи для бинарных файлов — штука практически бессмысленная. но если больше нечем заняться, то: https://superuser.com/q/283008/454489

Comment: @alexanderbarakin патчить EXE - святое дело! Вот не хочет трой работать - приходится патчить...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, я в курсе про легенды о том, как хакеры в те времена, когда компьютеры были большими, читали шестнадцатиричный код «с листа» и даже набирали с клавиатуры код загрузчика операционной системы. вероятно, термин «пропатчить бинарник» (при всей его бессмысленной беспощадности) — родом из тех легенд.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да тащемта нет. Всякое может понадобиться...

Comment: Может лучше рассказать зачем всё это затевается? Академический интерес или надо решить конкретную задачу?

Comment: @donRumata, если вам так сильно интересно, то пока ради интереса, а потом для использования в целях создания патчей для удаления тех или иных уязвимостей в собственной программе.

Comment: Я не помню, могут ли diff и patch дифать и патчить бинарные файлы, но если они нужны под Windows, гуглите gnuwin diff и gnuwin patch. Или берите например mingw, там сразу куча стандартных утилит будет.

Comment: Эммм... может тогда лучше изучить `WixToolset` и обновлять софт как белые люди, а не с помощью грязных (для этой задачи) хаков? А то получается такой git4bin+система доставки патчей. Получается прям пакетный менеджер. Сильно дофига лишних телодвижений, имхо.

Comment: *xdiff* вам в помощь, но программы патча в исходниках обычно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, поток пошёл про легенды? В университете на курсе микропроцессорной техники на лабораторных работах приходилось и таким заниматься. Сейчас это ниша в основном исследователей по безопасности и разработчиков компиляторов.